# Swift AVPlayer throwing exception on simulator

Tags: swift, avplayer

I am working on an app which contains music and sound effects so am using AVPlayer and I am encountering a very strange bug which only seems effect the simulator.

So in one of the screens in the app, there is music that plays in the background. So on that screen, I have AVPlayer setup and starts the song. This was working fine yesterday, but today when running the app on the simulator, this exception is thrown

[image]

However the app has not crashed, if I hit continue button a few times, the app continues running. But it is making debugging on simulator very frustrating as this happens every single time I open this screen. This issue doesn't happen on device.

Whats stranger is, I had a similar issue yesterday on this app with AVPlayer. I couldn't figure out where the issue was, so I started copying the code across to a new project piece by piece, until the whole thing was copied across, and this issue was not occurring. Then today, the issue started again. If I copy this code across to another project, it will work fine for a while on simulator, but eventually this issue pops up again.

Has anyone else experienced these types of issues on the simulator with AVPlayer? Is there any way to resolve this? Any help would be much appreciated

Edit: Just in case, here is code for how AVPlayer is setup

```
var songPlayerItem : AVPlayerItem?
    var songPlayer : AVPlayer?

  func startSong()
    {
        let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(song!.id, ofType: "mp3")!)
        songPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: url)

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.itemDidFinishPlaying(_:)), name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: songPlayerItem)
        songPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: songPlayerItem!)
        songPlayer?.play()
    }

 func itemDidFinishPlaying(notification : NSNotification)
    {
        print("SongFinished")
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any exception breakpoints enabled in Xcode by any chance? And if you do, will they throw on only ObjC errors or also C++ errors?

Comment: I have the AllExceptions break point turned. Turning that off seems to resolve the issue. I usually always have that break point on, as it makes debugging quicker if something in the app crashes while I am running the app. But why does this cause this exception issue? Is this a known issue with AVPlayer?

Comment: I had the same problem and setting AllExceptions to only throw at ObjC fixed it for me. That way it still crashes if I've caused an error but not if there are errors in C++ code. I don't know why the exception occurs though...sorry

Comment: Well your answer fixes it, so if you want to leave it as answer, I will mark it as accepted. Hopefully if anyone else has same problem, they don't waste hours like I did looking in the wrong place :) Cheers

Comment: you're welcome, glad to have saved you some time. And yes, hopefully someone else will see this and not waste hours like you and I have

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As can be seen in the comments above the "problem" is that @AdamM had an Exception breakpoint in Xcode which was triggered when errors occurred somewhere in `AVPlayer`.

The workaround is to set the Exception breakpoint to only stop on Objective C errors as shown in this image

[image]

This still doesn't answer why the error occurs in the first place though, but at least you now no longer stop every time the error occurs.